# Many to Many relation with Model inheritance in Django

Tags: django, inheritance

I have an abstract object called parameter. parameter can be of several different types. For example - Numeric Parameter, Constant parameter, MultiValue parameter etc.
Each parameter can be related to many parameter of different types and vise versa.

After reviewing Django's doc on [Model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) I decided what I need is a simple [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes). An example of a many to many relation from the base class can be found later on in the docs.

```
class ParameterBase(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)    
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sort_order = models.DecimalField(null=False, max_digits=6, decimal_places=4)

    m2m = models.ManyToManyField('self',related_name='dependent_on')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ParameterConstant(ParameterBase):
    value = models.DecimalField(null=False, blank=False, max_digits=20 , decimal_places=4)

class ParameterNumeric(ParameterBase):
    minimum = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=20 , decimal_places=4)    
    maximum = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=20 , decimal_places=4)
```

So after syncing i could see that django created 4 tables -

```
CREATE TABLE "calc_parameterconstant_m2m" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "from_parameterconstant_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "to_parameterconstant_id" integer NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ("from_parameterconstant_id", "to_parameterconstant_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "calc_parameterconstant" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "description" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "sort_order" numeric(6, 4) NOT NULL,
    "value" numeric(20, 4) NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE "calc_parameterconstant_m2m" ADD CONSTRAINT "from_parameterconstant_id_refs_id_f893bb67" FOREIGN KEY ("from_parameterconstant_id") REFERENCES "calc_parameterconstant" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
ALTER TABLE "calc_parameterconstant_m2m" ADD CONSTRAINT "to_parameterconstant_id_refs_id_f893bb67" FOREIGN KEY ("to_parameterconstant_id") REFERENCES "calc_parameterconstant" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

CREATE TABLE "calc_parameternumeric_m2m" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "from_parameternumeric_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "to_parameternumeric_id" integer NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ("from_parameternumeric_id", "to_parameternumeric_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "calc_parameternumeric" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "description" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "sort_order" numeric(6, 4) NOT NULL,
    "minimum" numeric(20, 4),
    "maximum" numeric(20, 4)
)
```

Now, This is obviously was not my intention - I want to be able to connect a parameter of each type to parameters of other types as well. Is there any way to achieve this goal using Django ORM and model inheritance ?

If the base parameter model was a table on it's own with Many to Many relation to it self and the sub tables were connected with an unbinding one to one relation this might be a good solution here database wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) will solve your problem.  To use it, just remove `abstract = True` from the `ParameterBase.Meta` subclass (or remove that subclass completely).

When using multi-table inheritance, to access attributes of a particular subclass, Django has to know that you're dealing with that subclass.

For example, this will fail:

```
p = ParameterBase.objects.get(...)  # get a ParameterBase that is a ParameterConstant
print p.value
```

Instead, you would have to do this:

```
p = ParameterConstant.objects.get(...)
print p.value
```

Or this:

```
p = ParameterBase.objects.get(...)  # get a ParameterBase that is a ParameterConstant
print p.paramaterconstant.value
```

Comment: what is the added value of using multi table model inheritance rather then plain one to one field in separate models ?

Comment: Child classes still have access to attributes and methods of the parent class.  In this case, if p is an instance of ParameterConstant then p.description does what you would expect.  Also, things like `isinstance(p, ParameterBase)` work as expected since it uses normal python inheritance.  If you were using a OneToOneField, you would have to explicitly navigate to your "parent" class.  Using the OneToOneField isn't inheritance.

Comment: another difference i can think of is that a request for parameter with inheritance will probably cause query against both tables while using one to one allow lazy load of the additional parameters.

Comment: It depends.  `p = ParameterBase.objects.get(...)` will only fetch fields defined in the ParameterBase table, without a join.  Using `p.parameterconstant` triggers a query on the ParameterConstant table.  `p = ParameterConstant.objects.get(...)` does a single query on both tables with an INNER JOIN.

Comment: if i have a ParameterBase and i want the sub model i have to know my type. so during sub class initiation i need to set a type model in the parent... something like `super(ParameterBase,self.__class__.__name__)`

Comment: That is correct.  Alternatively you could look into Django's contenttypes framework, but in my experience that is a big can of worms and adds an extra layer of indirection.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this would be to replace

```
m2m = models.ManyToManyField('self',related_name='dependent_on')
```

with

```
m2m = models.ManyToManyField('ParameterBase', related_name='dependent_on')
```

but Django won't let you create an m2m field that points to a model that hasn't been installed yet or one that is abstract. At this point `ParameterBase` is both of those.

I'd do it like this

```
class Parameter(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)    
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sort_order = models.DecimalField(null=False, max_digits=6, decimal_places=4)

class ParameterType(models.Model):
    parameter = models.ForeignKey(Parameter)
    related_parameters = models.ManyToManyField(Parameter,related_name='dependent_on')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ParameterConstant(ParameterType):
    value = models.DecimalField(null=False, blank=False, max_digits=20 , decimal_places=4)

class ParameterNumeric(ParameterType):
    minimum = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=20 , decimal_places=4)    
    maximum = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=20 , decimal_places=4)
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty interesting idea. aren't you missing a one to one link between the sub models to the base model ? you get the associations from the m2m but you also need the base parameter of the current sub class.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a **ManyToMany** field in an **abstract parent class**, you should provide a unique **related_name** as [stated in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name)... in your case, this should go fine:

`m2m = models.ManyToManyField('self',related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_m2m')`